# R output for ggplot-bar is giving wrong y axis value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am reading data from a csv file.The data set contains many variables.
proto Data set

[image: As shown in the figure]

My output :

[image]

My Code:

```
s=read.csv("Data 10.csv")
 y=s$Run.Rate[1]
 plot.new()
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))
 ggplot(s,aes(Location,y )) +geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="red" )
```

But my output gives a bar having a Y value of 65. Although it should be giving 1.235 as the y axis value.
Please help

Comment: Try `y = Run.Rate` instead of just `y`

Comment: ggplot(s,aes(Location,y )) +geom_col(fill="red" )

Comment: I tried this but still the same :   ggplot(s,aes(Location,y )) +geom_col(fill="red" )

Comment: You haven't told ggplot what to plot on the y axis. If you want to plot Location against `Run.Rate` you need `aes(Location, Run.Rate)`

Comment: ggplot(s,aes(Location,Run.Rate )) + geom_col(fill="red" )  Tried this too. but still the same

Comment: Please type `dput(s)` into the console and copy the output into your clipboard. Then edit your question (using the edit link under your question) and paste the result into your question. This should be an easy fix if we can see your actual data (pictures of data are useless)

Comment: You probably have all the y axis values stacked on top of each other. Are your `Location` values all the same? If so, what is it you are trying to show on the x axis?

Comment: Hi Cameron, thank you very much for your help

Comment: not necessary to do `plot.new()` and `par(mfrow=c(1,1)` - these are commands for base R graphics, and `ggplot` uses grid graphics